# In Netbeans+Ant, how do I avoid wsimport rebuilding web service clients every build?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build, wsimport

I'm on a project where we use NetBeans (6.8). We use several different web services, which we have added as web service references, and Netbeans auto-generates the Ant `wsimport` scripts for us. Very handy, with one drawback: The web service clients are recompiled every time `ant` is invoked. This slows down the build process considerably and has caused the number of [sword-related injuries, maimings and deaths](http://xkcd.com/303/) to skyrocket.

Normally, I'd fix this by changing the `wsimport` element from

```
<wsimport 
    sourcedestdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/PonyService"
    destdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/PonyService"
    wsdl="${wsdl-PonyService}" 
    catalog="catalog.xml" 
    verbose="true"/>
```

to

```
<wsimport 
    sourcedestdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/PonyService"
    destdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/PonyService"
    wsdl="${wsdl-PonyService}" 
    catalog="catalog.xml" 
    verbose="true">
    <produces dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/PonyService" />
</wsimport>
```

But I can't, 'cause this part of the Ant script is auto-generated. If I right-click the `PonyService` web service reference and select *Edit Web Service Attributes* ⇒ *`wsimport` options*, I can add attributes to the `wsimport` element, but not child elements.

So: **How do I add the `produces` child element to `wsimport` other than hacking the auto-generated Ant script?**

Or more generally: **How do I make the NetBeans-generated `wsimport` *not* recompile the web service clients every time I build?**

*(Also featured on the [NetBeans EE forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=76756).)*

Comment: Struggling with same issue in NetBeans 7.1, not adept enough yet with the wsimport options to understand why the depend/produces nodes work or how to change them. Hoping someone will stumble on this and provide more info on how to stop WSDL from getting polled on every rebuild.

Comment: @TonyG, good luck. The best solution is probably switching to Maven or some other non-IDE-dependent build system (like SBT).

Answer (score 3):

I may have an answer to this moldy question. The auto-code generation is intended to provide the Project with a web service client. The code is generated under a separate Web Service package folder, and the generated package is under that. Once that code has been generated, auto-generation is no longer required. The code is there to be used.

BACKUP EVERYTHING **BEFORE** DOING ANYTHING!

Drag/drop the generated code package from that folder to your primary source folder. The Web Service package folder disappears of course because nothing is in there. The Web Service client definition remains - this is where we'd typically refresh the definition. Delete that. It's no longer needed. Now do a Clean Rebuild. The result is a package of code within your project that looks just like everything else you've written - and the remote web service is not queried on every build.

Yes, you've lost the ability to dynamically regenerate the code from the WSDL, but if you really need to do that, just rename the current package, then regenerate new code and repeat as above and delete the redundant code when you're comfortable. You can also delete the META-INF nodes from the source tree. I found it took a couple delete operations to do this. After deleting everything except the .java code modules and doing a rebuild. My code did the remote connection without a problem.

I did as above when I realized that the generated code was being ignored by Subversion. The generated folders didn't contain a .svn file, so I couldn't commit that code into my repository. The only way to integrate the code into the project was to physically copy it in - and then I realized that this other problem was also solved.

It took 2 years to get a solution but I hope this helps someone...

Comment: If I could give you triple points for this answer, I would. Tried a lot of similar variations but this was the only thing that kept the classes working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NetBeans 6.9? I only ask because my `jaxws-build.xml` looks different to yours (all auto-NetBeans-generated).

```
<wsimport 
    sourcedestdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ListProductsService" 
    destdir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ListProductsService"
    wsdl="${wsdl-ListProductsService}"
    catalog="catalog.xml"
    extension="true"
    verbose="true" 
    wsdlLocation="file:/C:/NetBeansProjects/wsclient/ListProductsService.wsdl" 
    xendorsed="true">
    <depends file="${wsdl-ListProductsService}"/>
    <produces dir="${build.generated.dir}/jax-wsCache/ListProductsService"/>
</wsimport>
```

The above `wsclient` project is able to be cleaned and built without the web service reference being online.

Comment: These are legacy projects which were made before I showed up, with I think NetBeans 6.7 or earlier. I've noticed that some of the projects actually have their depends/produces elements set up OK, while others don't, so it seems there should be some way to make 'em work. The annoying thing is that regenerating the `jaxws-build.xml` doesn't help, regardless of NB version. Oh well, we're migrating to Maven soon, anyway, and hopefully we'll have more luck than @user369572 did...